# get text & value from asp.net treeview using jquery/javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I have a TreeView controller on my web page. When I'm adding the nodes in the TreeView, I'm setting the property `SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None` (I have the checkbox option activated, so I don't want the selection). Because of this, when I try:

```
  var node = document.getElementById("treeViewID");
  var value = node.href.substring(node.href.indexOf(",") + 3, node.href.length - 2);
  var text = node.innerHTML;
```

I get error because `.href` is not available.

Do you know a possibility of having access at .href of the node, but in the same time to keep the selection off?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the page source, something like $('#treeViewID').html() should give you the html inside that DOM element using Jquery